# Add TabBar on SearchDelegate Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a tab bar on Search Delegate. I want to show the results of products and user's profiles on the same search screen. I was trying to get a controller from the parent class and implement in delegate class but nothing happend(I wasn't getting any error)

Currently, my problem is I want to rebuild the build suggestion widget but I don't have any idea how to do that. Because the tab button widget has a different build context I can't rebuild the Suggestion widget.
hope you understand please ignore my grammar mistakes

```
class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  final TabController tabController;
  CustomSearchDelegate(this.tabController);

  var currentIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> tabs = [Text("Tab 1"), Text("Tab 2")];

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      Icon(Icons.clear),
    ];
    // TODO: implement buildActions
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
    // TODO: implement buildLeading
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
    // TODO: implement buildResults
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  PreferredSizeWidget buildBottom(BuildContext context) {
    return PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(50.0),
        child: StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) => DefaultTabController(
            length: 2,
            child: TabBar(
              onTap: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  currentIndex = index;
                });
              },
              indicatorColor: Colors.red,
              tabs: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    "Products",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    "Users",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final categoriesList =
        Provider.of<PopularServiceList>(context).dummy.where((element) {
      return element.title.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase());
    });
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return tabs[currentIndex];
      },
    );
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```